# Bar Chart with significance stars

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am new to d3 js.

I would like to create a simple bar chart, with significance bars with asterixes, like below.

[image: stars]

How would I go about doing this? Obviously I can make the normal bar charts as per the examples in the documentation, but I'm specifically falling short on the bars/asterixes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For something this custom, I would just draw the `paths` myself.  For example, I put this together in about 15 minutes.  Note, that I fudged the error bar calculations and it assumes the first bar is the tallest.

```
  svg.selectAll(".errorBar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d, i) {
      var rV = "";
      if (i === 0) {
        rV += "M" + (x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() * 0.5) + " " + y(d.value);
        rV += "L" + (x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() * 0.5) + " " + (y(firstValue.value) - ((data.length - 1) * 25));
        return rV;
      }
      var errorY = (y(d.value) - y(d.value) / 6);
      rV += "M" + (x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() * 0.5) + " " + y(d.value);
      rV += "L" + (x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() * 0.5) + " " + errorY;
      rV += "M" + (x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() * 0.25) + " " + errorY;
      rV += "L" + (x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() * 0.75) + " " + errorY;
      rV += "M" + (x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() * 0.5) + " " + (errorY - 10);
      rV += "L" + (x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() * 0.5) + " " + (y(firstValue.value) - (i * 25));
      rV += "M" + (x(firstValue.letter) + x.rangeBand() * 0.5) + " " + (y(firstValue.value) - (i * 25));
      rV += "L" + (x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() * 0.5) + " " + (y(firstValue.value) - (i * 25));
      return rV;

    })
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)


  svg.selectAll(".starText")
    .data(data.filter(function(d,i){ return i > 0; }))
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('dx',function(d,i){
      return ((x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand()) / 2);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d,i){
      return y(firstValue.value) - ((i+1) * 25);
    })
    .style('text-anchor', 'start')
    .text('****')
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7bDQQN6CusDsZlev3kJl?p=preview).

Looks like:

[image]